# grammar Antlr Java - identify "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE"

Tags: java, plsql, grammar, antlr4

I'm trying to write a small java program to identify the "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE" existing in my packages (Oracle). My goal is identify the dynamic sql. I use the PLSQL grammar produced by ANTLR4. https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/plsql. I can't extract this information.

Can anyone help me with solving this case?

A million thanks in advance

Comment: Just to notice, do you know that EXECUTE IMMEDIATE is not the only way to execute dynamic SQL?

Comment: yes... but it s a first step...

Answer (score 0):

Use a listener or a visitor generated by ANTLR.

You're looking for `execute_immediate` rule.
Each occurence of the rule means you've encountered a new `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement.